# Apple Mach-O Error Xcode - Really Confused

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, kiip

I was working on implementing the Kiip.me framework into my iOS App. I have added the framework and everything and linked it, but when I run it I get tons of errors in the Apple Mach-O. I am also getting a warning for a file I deleted a long time ago from Google analytics which it is still looking for even after I removed all references. Here is the error code, my main issue is the errors that say:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Kiip", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  objc-class-ref in CircleTableViewController.o
```

&

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But here is the full error code:

Ld /Users/Coconido/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CircleCreator-dbjnngeqphrtevdurkdpgggxapny/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CircleCreator.app/CircleCreator normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle Creator/CircleCreator"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/Coconido/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CircleCreator-dbjnngeqphrtevdurkdpgggxapny/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle\ Creator/CircleCreator/GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.02/GoogleAnalytics/Library -L/Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle\ Creator/CircleCreator/Images/openkit-ios.1.0.2/OpenKitSDK -F/Users/Coconido/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CircleCreator-dbjnngeqphrtevdurkdpgggxapny/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle\ Creator/CircleCreator/Images/openkit-ios.1.0.2/OpenKitSDK/Vendor -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle\ Creator/CircleCreator/CircleCreator/Kiip-iOS-SDK-v2 -F/Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle\ Creator/CircleCreator/Kiip-iOS-SDK-v2 -F/Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle\ Creator/CircleCreator -filelist /Users/Coconido/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CircleCreator-dbjnngeqphrtevdurkdpgggxapny/Build/Intermediates/CircleCreator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CircleCreator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CircleCreator.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework CoreLocation -framework KiipSDK -framework PassKit -framework AdSupport -framework CoreTelephony -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Social -framework Accounts -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -lsqlite3 -framework StoreKit -framework CoreData -lz -framework MessageUI -framework iAd -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Coconido/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CircleCreator-dbjnngeqphrtevdurkdpgggxapny/Build/Intermediates/CircleCreator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CircleCreator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CircleCreator_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Coconido/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CircleCreator-dbjnngeqphrtevdurkdpgggxapny/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CircleCreator.app/CircleCreator

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle Creator/CircleCreator/GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.02/GoogleAnalytics/Library'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle Creator/CircleCreator/CircleCreator/Kiip-iOS-SDK-v2'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle Creator/CircleCreator/Kiip-iOS-SDK-v2'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle Creator/CircleCreator/KiipSDK.framework/KiipSDK, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Coconido/Documents/Circle Creator/CircleCreator/KiipSDK.framework/KiipSDK (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Kiip", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in CircleTableViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Your project is still referencing the libraries for GoogleAnalytics (most likely in build phases->Link Binary With Libraries).  That is the first error (just a warning really).

The second error you are dealing with is with the included framework Kiip.  It doesn't have a 64 bit version of the framework, so if your project build settings allows for the building of a 64 bit app it will not compile because you reference Kiip and cannot use it.

Three solutions to that:

1. Remove Kiip from your project.
2. Find out how to build the Kiip framework for 64 bit
3. Make your project not build 64 bit architectures.  (build settings->valid architectures)

Comment: How can i build a framework for 64bit, i managed to get rid of the errors but now when i run it it shows a black screen, can i just make the app without 64 bit features?

Comment: Don't bother unless there is some performance reason. 64 bit devices are perfectly happy to run in 32Bit. Just compile for armv7. armv7s is just the iPhone5 processor and is barely different that armv7 except for a few relatively unimportant instructions.

Answer (score 0):

`Undefined symbols for architecture` errors are thrown by the linker when it can't find an object file to link against. You mentioned that you've linked the framework - I would double check that you *have* properly linked the framework. (In Xcode, you can find the list of linked binaries under your project's file > `Build Phases` > `Link Binary with Libraries`.)

If all of your linker flags are set up correctly and the problem persists after a clean build, the `Kiip.me` framework might not contain code for `x86_64` (that is, the iPhone Simulator).